# here-map-widget-for-jupyter outdated

Tags: here-api, jupyter-lab, heremaps, here-olp

Is there a method to make `here-map-widget-for-jupyter` function in the most recent Python environment?

The command `pip install here-map-widget-for-jupyter` installs without issues, but the widget isn't functioning at all showing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've got it working.

I tried this:

- completely uninstalling my environment
- installing Anaconda https://www.anaconda.com/download
- installing the widget using conda (it runs very slow but resolves dependencies better)

  `conda install -c conda-forge here-map-widget-for-jupyter`

It doesn't work in DataSpell, which I used to use, but it works in a browser now.